# How to obtain Declared Methods in any given java class

Tags: java, reflection

I understand that the following exists:

```
Class clazz = Class.forName("SomeClassWithinSameDirectory);

Method methods[] = clazz.getDeclaredMethods();
```

but, from what I've tried, this only works given that the class I'm using is within the same directory as the class that has my main method.

Does Java have a simple way of working around this problem? I've been googling a bit but have come up with nothing. Someone guide me in the right direction? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `this only works given that the class I'm using is within the same directory as the class that has my main method.` What? `Class.forName` expects a fully qualified name.

Comment: My wording might be incorrect, not that experienced in programming. What I'm trying to say is that I can only get declared methods of classes that are in the same directory as the class that I'm using Class.ForName in.

Comment: What happens when you try it with other classes?

Comment: If it's outside the directory I get a Class Not Found Exception.

Comment: Look into what a `fully qualified class name` means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you can just use `Class clazz = Class.forName("my.package.SomeClass");` and reflection will attempt to load that class, or throw a `ClassNotFoundException`.

Also take a look at the more complex alternate `forName` signature, which lets you choose whether the class should be initialized and with which `ClassLoader` to do so.